# Can I load a whole Namespace within one file?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I would like to combine all classes from one namespace into one file instead of loading them each. Yes I know that the loader should not be used in productive environments but these namespaces are seldom used.

Lets say I have the namespace

```
App.Employee.*
```

I now want to load the whole `App.Employee` namespace within one file/request. For me this sounds like as it should be possible but I didn't managed to get it working cause the loader was looking for a class named `App.Employee`.

So is this possible out of the box or is it theoretical possible or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to build your application, including less used parts. It doesn't matter much if your app will load 20 or 30 seconds upfront but later on the delay may be more pronounced and noticeable. Sencha Cmd can help you with that.

If you still think your app can benefit from dynamic loading, use `Ext.Loader.loadScript`. It has `callback` parameter that kicks in when the script in question is loaded, which gives you an action point. The script shouldn't necessarily be an Ext class, any JavaScript will do - including a part of application in compressed form.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I didn't tested it yet but it sound promising :) Maybe you would take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998325/why-do-i-get-a-ref-object-back-when-calling-a-refrence) too?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all namespace App.Employee.* in one file /App/employee.js and then load it with file full path, when you need it.

```
Ext.require("/App/employee")
```

**UPD**. I found some problems with it too. Ext.loader dont wait for employee.js. And it throws exceptions, when classes in employee.js has dependencies.
Try `Ext.syncRequire("/App/employee")` instead. It worked fine on my tests.

And dont forget to declare full path to file (from your webroot).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I can require a file that way and stop the the load from looking for a class named like the file + namespace. I will give this a try. I this work it may exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This does not work. ExtJS is looking for a class named like the given path, but it is just namespace so there is no class. -1 If I am mistaken tell me where I am wrong and or fix your answer

Comment: I will not test your edit cause @AlexanderTokarev supplied the answer I was looking for (yet not tested) but I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to put all the classes in one js file and load that very file (just copy and pasta the code from all the single files into a new one and name it something like `App.employee.js`). 
It's not possible to load multiple files in one Ajax request, so the loader can't help you there.

See the [Ext docs for details on the loader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader).

FYI:

Ext uses `CamelCase` naming of classes and namespaces. Their namespaces all start with a lower case character, their classes all start with an uppercase character. That makes it much easier to distinguish between both types.
It's advisable to follow that convention. More on that can be found [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/class_system-section-2).

Comment: You can load any files with a Ajax request? As far as I know this is not possible at all due to the header of of the ajax request? Or did this only apply if I also want to save the file locally? Anyway I already tried what you suggested and as I wrote in my question I ended up with the error that there is no class named `App.Employee` which is correct, cause it is only a namespace.